# ASP.NET confirm delete in a grid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to add a confirm delete action to a grid. the problem is the way the "Delete" link is rendered.
my grid is built in code behind in vb.net.
i have this

```
colDelete.AllowDelete = True
colDelete.Width = "100"
AddHandler CType(gridSavedForLater, Grid).DeleteCommand, AddressOf dgDeleteSelectedIncident
```

and the sub is the following

```
Sub dgDeleteSelectedIncident(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridRecordEventArgs)

    Dim message As String = "Are you sure you want to delete this incident?"
    Dim caption As String = "Confirm Delete"
    Dim result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, caption, Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    'If (result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) Then
    'Else
    ' MessageBox("Are you sure you want to delete this incident?")
    'Get the VehicleId of the row whose Delete button was clicked
    'Dim SelectedIncidentId As String = e.Record("IncidentId")

    ''Delete the record from the database
    'objIncident = New Incidents(SelectedIncidentId, Session("userFullName"))

    'objIncident.DeleteIncident()
    ''Rebind the DataGrid
    LoadSavedForLater()
    ''        End If

End Sub
```

i need to add a javascript confirm dialog when this sub is called. i can do it with a windows form messagebox but that does not work on the server.

pleae help
joe

Comment: You simply need to write a javascript function that handles the onclick event of the button and blocks/allows postback according to the prompt result.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot show a MessageBox in ASP.NET since it would be shown on the server. So you need a javascript `confirm` onclick of the delete button. Therefor you don't need to postback to the server first. You can attach the script on the initial load of the `GridView`.

A good place would be in `RowDataBound` of the `GridView`:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            ' if it's a custom button in a TemplateField '
            Dim BtnDelete = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("BtnDelete"), Button)
            BtnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete?');"
            ' if it's an autogenerated delete-LinkButton: '
            Dim LnkBtnDelete As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)
            LnkBtnDelete.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete?');"            
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, a common method of notifying users in a web page of a status change (save, delete, update, etc.) is having an update element in your HTML. Basically, a label (or whatever) that you'll set with updates to the user.

*"Your changes have been successfully saved."* or *"An error was encountered when trying to save your update."*, for example. You can set the color red for an error or whatever your programming heart desires, stylistically.

I kind of like this approach as a pop-up always feels more like a WinForm thing to me. Either works, so I just thought I'd suggest another approach.